# Objective-C getting all images from file

Tags: objective-c

I am getting images from url and saving to file.
My codes for saving and loading:

```
-(void) saveImage:(UIImage *)image withFileName:(NSString *)imageName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
    if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"png"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"jpg"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Image Save Failed\nExtension: (%@) is not recognized, use (PNG/JPG)", extension);
    }
}
-(UIImage *) loadImage:(NSString *)fileName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
    UIImage * result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@", directoryPath, fileName, extension]];

    return result;
}
```

> Downloading images, saving to file and loading from file are
>   successfully working. But I want to get all images that I save to
>   file. So I don't want to specify image name. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save the images you have, make some naming convention, i.e. image01.png, image02.png, image03.png so when you'll load them you can simply iterate through a For Loop and call the function you already wrote:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= imagesCount; i++) {    
    NSString* twoDigitNumber;
    if (i < 10) {
        twoDigitNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", i];
    }
    else {
        twoDigitNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
    }

    NSString* imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%@", twoDigitNumber];

    UIImage* image = [self loadImage:imageName inDirectory:......]; // Complete your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must know what you want to read. There are probably many approaches - here are two:

1. store the filenames of each file and iterate over those filenames.
2. store the images in some directory and loop over the directory contents.